# Indentation in ERB templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have the following entry in an `erb` template:

```
# Lorem Ipsum...
<% unless @foo['bar'] == nil %>
    <% @foo['bar'].each do |property, value| %>
        <%= "zaz.#{property} #{value}" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That is parsed to:

```
# Lorem Ipsum...
       zaz.property value
```

How can I remove the leading spaces so that lines are not indented in the resolved template?

I would like to avoid using something like:

```
# Lorem Ipsum...
<% unless @foo['bar'] == nil %>
    <% @foo['bar'].each do |property, value| %>
<%= "zaz.#{property} #{value}" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can offer is hackish adding `<%- 'whatever here' %>` before the `<%= %>` entry:

```
<% [1,2,3].each do |f| %>
    <%- 1 %><%= f %>
<% end %>
```

it outputs in irb

```
irb(main):018:0> ERB.new(File.read('f.txt'), nil, '-').result
=> "\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n\n"
```

Rails doc claims, that default value for ERB trim_mode is `-`
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-view

And according to https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-erb/ ERB should remove spaces before `<%-` when `-` mode is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You could indent the code instead of the ERB tags:

```
# Lorem Ipsum...
<% unless @foo['bar'] == nil %>
<%   @foo['bar'].each do |property, value| %>
<%=    "zaz.#{property} #{value}" %>
<%   end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Although this might do the trick, it is very similar to the solution I want to avoid using. (The last chunk of code in the question)
I am looking for a more _correct_ solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you're controlling the string passed to `ERB.new`, then you can make yourself a new tag to use.

Given a template in a file:

```
<%~ 'hello' %>
    <%~ 'world' %>
<%~ '!' %>
```

Do:

```
string = File.read(file_path).gsub('<%~', '<%-%><%=')
print ERB.new(string, trim_mode: '-').result
```

And get:

```
hello
world 
!
```

I'd love it if ERB would include this tag itself, but until then I'm doing it myself.